# VisualVM Calibration Step Hangs with Windows 10

Tags: java, code-profiling

Situation:

I have installed VisualVM 1.3.8 on my Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (and not using the one that came with the JDK 8).

I would like to use this to Profile a Java (Play) App.

What Happens:

When starting the CPU profiling, it first asks that I need to calibrate, and when that happens it hangs at the stage.

[The Display showing the hanging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tas82.png)

What I Have Tried:

I tried this on MacOS 8, and it does go through the calibration steps OK.

I have edited the etc/visualvm.conf to disable the d3d pipline feature.

visualvm_default_options="-J-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false -J-client -J-Xms24m -J-Xmx256m -J-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions -J-Dnetbeans.accept_license_class=com.sun.tools.visualvm.modules.startup.AcceptLicense -J-Dsun.jvmstat.perdata.syncWaitMs=10000 -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true"

The Goal:

Get the calibration process to complete.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37632783/visualvm-cpu-memory-profiler-stuck-at-connecting-to-the-target-jvm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java VisualVM hangs connecting to locally process launched from eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494095/java-visualvm-hangs-connecting-to-locally-process-launched-from-eclipse)

Answer (score 17):

I've found a [mailing list entry](http://markmail.org/message/g2gefpmxfnk42cgu) describing the same problem.

The solution is to start VisualVM from command-line using:

```
jvisualvm.exe "-J-Dorg.netbeans.profiler.separateConsole=true"
```

Comment: I've been having this problem for while now.. that fixed it, thanks.

Comment: Running that command returned the following error:

`There are parameters but nobody wants to proces them: [.netbeans.profiler.separateConsole=true]`


However, when I put the options between double-quotes, it worked.

    `jvisualvm.exe "-J-Dorg.netbeans.profiler.separateConsole=true"`